# 2015 Subaru Impreza premium

Tags: subaru, acceleration, impreza

I have an issue where my rpms have been much higher than normal when I accelerate at first. It just started happening over the last month and also I’ve noticed my car lags when it accelerates lately as well. There are no lights on my dash and I just had my oil changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: If you have an automatic transmission, it could be slipping, causing the engine to rev without appreciable vehicles acceleration. It might just be low on transmission fluid, or it might be broken.

Comment: It’s a CVT transmission and it’s only got 40,000